# How to show model images in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have such models.py file

```
class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORIES = {
        ('Computer', 'Комп\'ютер'),
        ('Smartphone', 'Смартфон')
    }
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=False)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CATEGORIES)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
```

In settings.py i DON'T have media variables/dirs

Also i try to show images in such way

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Каталог{% endblock %}

   {% block content %}
     {% for i in products %}
      <img src="{ static i.photo.url }">
      {{i.title}}
     {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Result:
[image]

I add my model objects in Django Admin

[image]

Comment: In the browser, if you look at the source of the HTML, is the URL of the image correct? If you look at the Network tab of the developer tools in the browser, do you find any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see below configuration, have you done?

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # urls/path
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

your HTML file

```
    {% if i.photo %}
    <img src="{{ i.photo.url }}"> 
     {% endif %}
```

Comment: both static and settings are not defined in urls.py

Comment: then please add it

Comment: what do i need to add?

Comment: just add below as show in example 
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: yes, i added but static and settings are not defined

Comment: please import below 

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

Comment: The 'photo' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: img not present in queryset

Comment: thank you so much, it works :) Is it possible to change photo size for each of Product in my queryset?

Comment: yes you can change it by `CSS` add this line in your `CSS` file `img{width:400px;height:400px;}`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the static tag.

```
<img src="{{ i.photo.url }}">
```

Comment: It didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this.
and run the collectstatic command to

```
 <img src="{%  static '/logo.png' %}"/>

 python manage.py collectstatic
```

Answer (score 0):

> In settings.py i DON'T have media variables/dirs

you have to set `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in `settings.py` and set the URL of each in `urls.py` because by default, Django stores files locally, using the `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` settings. The examples below assume that you’re using these defaults.
check the official [doc.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/#managing-files)

**step - 1**
configure media and static files like this

add this in your `settings.py`

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static_cdn'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

and add this in your `urls.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] 

if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```